# Target only those rows where every value is zero

Tags: tableau-api, zero

**UPDATE (18TH APRIL 2018)**

My requirements have changed slightly in relation to this problem (as I now need to also have the ability to keep zero-value rows), but the underlying element remains which is the ability to target rows which contain zero-values all the way across.

I have adjusted the title to reflect the updated requirements accordingly.

As such, this example might help explain things a little more clearly.

In this example, I want to keep only those rows that have zeroes all the way across.

I would keep rows `4`, `7`, `9`, `12`, `15`, `16`, `17`, and `19` (the rows with red dots beside them):

[image]

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I want to exclude rows in my dataset from displaying where **every value is zero** and not just some values.

I have applied a filter to exclude zero values, and that has worked partially in that it has excluded the all-zero rows, but it has also hidden the cells where there is a zero present in rows which have values other than zero.

[image]

The problem with this is that I want to display the zero values where there are other `>0` values in the row; I only want to exclude zero values where the entire row contains zeroes.

Conversely, I want to also be able to display **only those rows where every value is zero** in a separate sheet.

When I reverse the filter, as such, it shows me the inverse of those rows which are still visible with the non-zero filter on (white spaces show where there are non-zero values):

[image]

How can this be achieved?

**EDIT:**

To make things clearer, **I want to remove rows where every value / cell is zero**.

I want to display any row that contains a number other than zero, even if it is just one element in the entire row.

(For reference, neither of the images I have posted are ideal as each one is somewhere between the two.)

**Some background:**

The values relate to minutes that a call centre operator is available within each respective hour of the working day.

Consider this example:

```
     ___|_1100_1159_|_1200_1259_|_1300_1359_|_1400_1459_|_1500_1559_|
     _A_|_____0_____|_____15____|_____10____|_____45____|_____10____|
     _B_|_____0_____|_____0_____|_____0_____|_____0_____|_____0_____|
     _C_|_____0_____|_____0_____|_____0_____|_____0_____|_____0_____|
     _D_|_____5_____|_____0_____|_____0_____|_____0_____|_____0_____|
```

After applying my function/formula to this table, my desired result is for rows `B` and `C` to no longer be shown and only for rows `A` and `D` to remain.

The function would be something like this:

```
IF(SUM OF ENTIRE ROW VALUE ACROSS ALL HOURS == 0)
THEN EXCLUDE ROW
ELSE DISPLAY ROW
END IF
```

Unfortunately, the problem is not as simple as either hiding or showing zero-values; it is a conditional problem whereby I want to hide all zero value rows, unless there is a non-zero value present in the row, in which case I want to show the row and also the zero values in said row.

Comment: Do you mean you want to exclude rows in your data source that have zeroes for every field (column)? In SQL, you would use a Where clause for example. Or do you mean you want to exclude rows in the aggregate query result that have a zero for each (aggregated) measure? In SQL, you would use a Having clause for example. Both are possible, but they are different kinds of filters. Put more simply, What exactly do the columns in your question represent? columns of data or columns of aggregate query results?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are seeking a row-level filter to identify individual rows in your data source, then:

1. Create a calculated field called, say, **Zero_In_All_Fields?**, or whatever makes the most sense to you. My occasional convention is to name boolean valued fields with a ? at the end. Define the field as `[Field_1] = 0 and [Field_2] = 0` or whetever makes sense. This field will return true for data rows that meet your condition.
2. Put that new calculated field on the Filter Shelf. Select True or False as desired.

You can also use your boolean calculated field in calculations, other shelves for visual effects, set conditions etc.

**REVISED**

The approach above shows how to filter out data rows -- basically a WHERE clause in SQL speak. If what you want to do instead is to filter out some dimension, say Employee, who has all zero totals, that is a different filter to generate effecting a SQL HAVING clause.

I'm assuming each row in your visualization shows the totals for some measures per employee. in that case, put Employee on the Filter shelf, edit the filter, select the Condition tab, and enter a condition similar to `Sum([Field_1]) = 0 and Sum([Field_2]) = 0`

Obviously the choice of field names and aggregation functions, sum, min, max etc, depends on the problem.

In this particular case, you could simplify the condition to `Sum([Field_1] + [Field_2]) = 0` if your fields never have negative values.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I have already tried this approach but it results in the images shown in my question. I also need it to show the entire rows where there is at least one non-zero value present (even if all the other elements are zero). I will update my question again to make it a little clearer.

Comment: In your edited question, you talking about excluding "rows" and also about displaying "rows". Tableau deals with 2 kinds of things called rows - rows in the data source and rows in the visualization. Very different things, especially in the normal situation where you are doing aggregate queries (i.e. have left the default value checked for Aggregation under the Analysis menu). This answer shows how to filter out data rows.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a second approach. Hard to tell which you wanted from the question.